# Redirect non www requests without redirecting sub-domains

Tags: redirect, dns

To replace a legacy web site, a client has pointed their DNS at my server where a new version of the website exists.

However they still serve http://support.example.com from their own server.

I have noticed that non-www requests, e.g. http://example.com still point to their own server, therefore show the old web site.

**How can I point non-www requests, http://example.com at my server without breaking the functionality of their 'support' sub-domain?**

- The client's server is a Microsoft server, mine is Linux/Apache
- Edit: Changing the DNS 'A' record will not break the existing sub-domain
- I know I could add an index.html page to the front of the old site, but if it was ever deleted the page requests would cease to work
- I can't use mod-rewrite because I don't have access to their web server files

---

> **PROPOSED SOLUTION:**
>
> On the client DNS, create an **A**
>   record for:
>
> - support.example.com – IP of the client's server
> - example.com – IP of my server
> - www.example.com - IP of my server
>
> No need for any DNS changes on my server regarding this domain

Answer (score 1):

Changing the `A` record for `example.com` won't affect the `A` record for `support.example.com`.